# question regarding uniform space

Tags: general-topology

If I have a uniformity defined on a space X, what does it mean for a subset to be a closed member of the uniformity?

Answer (score 0):

Uniformity implies we have a topology on $X$ and thus on $X \times X$. A closed member of the uniformity is (in my usual definition) some subset of $X \times X$ that now is assumed to be closed as well.

Comment: Ohhh I see what you mean... So we actually took the induced topology from the uniformity, took a closed set, say U, and UXU is closed in the product topology?

Comment: @AvivEshed a closed set in $X \times X$ need not be of the form $U \times U$ for $U$ closed in $X$. Such sets will only contain the diagonal (as they must) when $X = U$, so we get only one closed uniformity member that way.

Comment: $C \subset X \times X$ such that $X \times X \setminus C$ is a union of basic open sets of the form $U \times V$, where $U,V$ open in $X$. But these are quite complicated in general.